# FFmpeg cropping: 'Invalid too big or non positive size for width '2304' or height '4096'

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to crop video to format 1080:1920, it works with most videos but sometimes it fails with an error like:

> Invalid too big or non positive size for width '2304' or height '4096'

Here is the code I am using:

```
import ffmpy

ffmpy.FFmpeg(inputs={"input.mp4": None}, outputs={"output.mp4": ["-y", "-vf", "crop=ih*(9/16):ih,scale=1080:1920", "-preset", "ultrafast"]})`
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is that `ih*(9/16) > frame_width`.

We can't crop a rectangle that exceeds the boundaries of the frame.

For example:
Assume the resolution of input.mp4 is 100x200 (100 is the width).
`ih = 200`
`ih*(9/16)` = `112.5`
We can't crop 112x200 pixels because the frame width is only 100 pixels...

---

For reproducing the issue, we may create synthetic video using FFmpeg (command line tool):

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=100x200:rate=1:duration=5 input.mp4
```

(The synthetic video is used only for demonstration).

---

When executing `ffmpy.FFmpeg(inputs={"input.mp4": None}, outputs={"output.mp4": ["-y", "-vf", "crop=ih*(9/16):ih,scale=1080:1920", "-preset", "ultrafast"]})`, we are getting an error message:

> Invalid too big or non positive size for width '112' or height '200'

---

For fixing the issue, we may check if `height*9/16 <= width`.
We may get the video resolution (`width` and `height`) using OpenCV (or any other package we find).
Now we can check `if height*9/16 <= width`, and use other cropping parameters if the condition is false.

---

Code sample:

```python
import ffmpy
import cv2

# Get video resolution using OpenCV
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('input.mp4')
width  = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
cap.release()

crop_w = height*9/16

if crop_w <= width:
    # We can do the cropping only when the cropped area is inside frame boundaries.
    ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(inputs={"input.mp4": None}, outputs={"output.mp4": ["-y", "-vf", "crop=ih*(9/16):ih,scale=1080:1920", "-preset", "ultrafast"]})
else:
    ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(inputs={"input.mp4": None}, outputs={"output.mp4": ["-y", "-vf", "crop=iw:iw*(16/9),scale=1080:1920", "-preset", "ultrafast"]})

ff.run()
```

---

Note: We don't really have to duplicate the part of the code (I used the duplication for demonstration).

Comment: Thank you!  You're mention of...

"We can't crop a rectangle that exceeds the boundaries of the frame."

helped me correct the issue I was having.  In my case, I changed iw*2:ih*2 to a higher value, like iw*8:ih8, and that worked